# Ruby on Rails: is there a way to pass a method pointer to a function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do this:

```
def assert_record_not_found(method, object, action, params)
   begin
     method action, params
     object.find_by_id(p.id).should_not be_nil
   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
     assert true
   end
end
```

but when I do the call:

```
assert_record_not_found(delete, MyObject, :destroy, {:id => o.id})
```

I get an error that delete has no arguments... which makes sense, given that delete is a rails testing function.

So, is there a way to pass a pointer to the method as an argument instead of passing the method itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use ruby blocks:

```
def assert_record_not_found(object, action, params, &block)
  begin
    block.call action, params
    object.find_by_id(p.id).should_not be_nil
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
    assert true
  end
end
```

And then call your method:

```
assert_record_not_found(MyObject, :destroy, {:id => o.id}) do |action, params| 
  delete action, params 
end
```

You can also get the method object and pass it to your function:

```
def assert_record_not_found(method, object, action, params, &block)
  begin
    method.call action, params
    object.find_by_id(p.id).should_not be_nil
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
    assert true
  end
end

delete = method(:delete)
assert_record_not_found(delete, MyObject, :destroy, {:id => o.id})
```

Using blocks is far more ruby-ish.

Comment: but how do you invoke def assert_record_not_found(object, action, params, &block)
?

Comment: Edited post to contain the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Object::send](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999) as an alternative.

Example code from the Ruby Docs:

```
class Klass
 def hello(*args)
   "Hello " + args.join(' ')
 end
end
k = Klass.new
k.send :hello, "gentle", "readers"   #=> "Hello gentle readers"
```